# REPLACE is not working inside plsql procedure

Tags: plsql

I am writing a procedure with a cursor that take table name and column name from a lookup table we have in DB. This table has a mapping of table name and columns.

These two info I am collecting in a variable and running a select query to see if the data in that column is number or not. for example:-

```
select TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(v_landing_column,'','')) 
from v_landing_table
```

Here `v_landing_column` is a column name and `v_landing_table` is a table name. One of the values in `v_landing_column` is `12,300` which is a number but because of `,` the loop flow is going into exception where I am dumping error record in a seperate table.

I tried using REPLACE also with above syntax but still flow is dumping this record with value `12,300` into error table. How to remove `,` from `12,300` inside plsql procedure using execute immediate?

Comment: It would help a lot if you provided a minimal reproducible example. You're explaining what is happening but I don't see how I can reproduce that...

Comment: My guess is that you have some spaces or other non-numeric characters in your data; what does it show when you do `select dump(v_landing_column) from <your_table> where <predicates that pick out the problem row>;`? When I run `SELECT dump(REPLACE('12,300', ',')) FROM dual;` I get `Typ=1 Len=5: 49,50,51,48,48`. Those last 5 numbers are the ASCII values of the 5 characters returned by the `REPLACE` function (you can check they correspond by doing `CHR()` on each value, e.g. `CHR(49)` returns "1")

Comment: I figured out the issue. the issue is somewhere else. i will close this thread and ask another question.